# jQuery specific Selector Question

Tags: jquery

I was wondering, I know that $(selector) returns a jQuery object, but say I have a series of div in the body such as:

```
<body>
<div> </div>
<div> </div>
<div> </div>
</body>
```

When I try $("div"), jQuery should return a jQuery object that is like an array of divs, BUT when I try to specify a certain div like $("div")[1], is this not a jQuery object? And if it isn't, I know I can't use .css() so how can I change the css of a specific div that I need to be determined dynamically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$("div")` returns an array of DOM elements.  `$("div")[1]` gets the 2nd element on the page, as a DOM element.  To make it back into a jQuery object, you can do `$($("div")[1])`.

I don't suggest you do that though.  You can use the [`:eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) to get the div you want.

```
$("div:eq(1)")
```

Or, you can use the [`.eq()` function](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

```
$("div").eq(1)
```

Comment: Beat me to it. I'm not sure why people keep breaking out the `.eq()` method and not doing the selector like you've demonstrated. :head-scratch:

Comment: @Brad because `.eq()` is nominally faster than `:eq()`. It's also easier to handle if `n` is a variable - `.eq(n)` is a lot easier than `:eq(" + n + ")`

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed and swift response! This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `.eq` http://api.jquery.com/eq/

```
$("div").eq(1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the jQuery wrapped element in the collection.
i.e.

```
$("div").eq(1).css()
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing this:

```
 $($("div")[1]).css()
```

Comment: Under **redundant** it says _See redundant_.

Answer (score 0):

`$("div")[1]` is not a jQuery object. You can even test it on your browsers JavaScript console on this very page. You can use the `$` function again to make it so `css` can be used:

```
$($("div")[1]).css("hello", "world");
```

Or, if your example is what you actually, exactly, need to do, do this instead:

```
$("body > div:nth-child(2)").css("hello", "world");
```

Comment: `nth-child` is not the same as `.eq(n)` or `$($()[n])`

Comment: @Alnitak: I never said it was... but in the example, the OP has some `<div>`s under `<body>`. Hence: "***Or, if your example is what you actually, exactly, need to do, do this instead:***"

Comment: the intent was to ensure people don't misinterpret your answer

Comment: Why does it have to be the same to be a valid selector?